# Use sp_addmessage to Write to EventLog with different Event ID

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have bunch of custom messages in SQL Server that I am writing to event log and I never realized that they all writing with same EVENTID 17063 in Application Event Log, how can I specify sp_addmessage to write a custom EvenID so that all are not logged with EVENTID 17063 ?

EXEC sp_addmessage 
    @msgnum = 90002, 
    @severity = 16,
    @msgtext = 
        N'some text',
    @lang = 'us_english',
    @with_log = 'TRUE',
@replace = 'replace' ;
ReplyQuote

Comment: I assume the objective is to allow you to distinguish different events in the event log?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that EVENTID 17063 indicates that the source for the event is SQL Server, so that is not something that you can change using the sp_addMessage stored procedure.

However, if you're able to use CLR, you can create a wrapper around the EventLog.WriteEntry method, which would allow you to change the EVENTID.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f6wy11we.aspx